# SQL query problems transpose MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

There are 2 simple tables

```
People:
person_id
Name 

Reading assestment
date
person_id
quality
speed
```

Trying to create sql query

```
SELECT 
  AVG(r.quality),
  AVG(r.speed),
FROM reading_assestment r,people p
where r.person_id =p.person_id
  and person_id="3"
```

Current output:

```
Quality  Speed
77      65
```

Outcome I am looking for:

```
Assestment Value
Quality      77
Speed        65
```

It is something to do with transpose , pivots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way is to start with your query and then unpivot using separate logic:

```
select (case when n = 1 then 'Quality' else 'Speed' end) as Assessment,
       (case when n = 1 then avg_quality else avg_speed end) as Value
from (select AVG(r.quality) as avg_quality, AVG(r.speed) as avg_speed
      from reading_assestment r join
           people p
           on r.person_id =p.person_id
      where person_id = 3
     ) t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
```

Comment: Liked the clever use of cross join! I was thinking of doing `(SELECT * FROM people WHERE person_id = 3 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM people WHERE person_id = 3)` and then joining reading_assestment

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  AggResults.person_id   AS person_id,
  Assesment.Name         AS AssessmentName,
  CASE WHEN Assessment.Name = 'Quality' THEN AggResults.AvgQuality
       WHEN Assessment.Name = 'Speed'   THEN AggResults.AvgSpeed
                                        ELSE NULL
  END                    AS AssessmentValue
FROM
(
  SELECT
    people.person_id   AS person_id,
    AVG(quality)       AS AvgQuality,
    AVG(speed)         AS AvgSpeed
  FROM
    reading_assessment
  INNER JOIN
    people
      ON reading_assessment.person_id = people.person_id
  GROUP BY
    people.person_id
)
  AS AggResults
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'Quality' AS Name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Speed'   AS Name
)
  AS Assessment
WHERE
  AggResults.person_id = 3
```

I moved the `= 3` to the outer query, just for ease of use.  Most optimisers will treat both options similarly.